# @Path as optional param?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

In my android project I use Retrofit:

```
@POST("/correspondents/{correspondent_id}")
    fun updateCorrespondent(@Path("correspondent_id") correspondentId: String, @Body body: JsonElement): Call<Void>
```

So I call from client like this:

```
 fun updateCorrespondent(correspondent: Correspondent, callback: Callback<Void>) {
        val call = myRestClient.updateCorrespondent(correspondent.id, correspondent.toUpdateJson())
        call.enqueue(callback)
    }
```

Nice, it's work fine.

But I need to do `@Path("correspondent_id")` optional.

I need to call from client like this:

```
fun updateCorrespondent(correspondent: Correspondent, callback: Callback<Void>) {
        val call = tangoRestClient.updateCorrespondent(correspondent.toUpdateJson())        
        call.enqueue(callback)
    }
```

Is it possible?

For now I use two separate methods:

```
@POST("/correspondents/{correspondent_id}")
    fun updateCorrespondent(@Path("correspondent_id") correspondentId: String, @Body body: JsonElement): Call<Void>

    @POST("/correspondents/create")
    fun createCorrespondent(@Body body: JsonElement): Call<Void>
```

Is it possible to use only one method with optional `@Path` ?

Comment: Is your API endpoint support this?
What will be default value for correspondent_id in your api end point

Comment: @POST("/correspondents/{correspondent_id}")
    fun updateCorrespondent(@Path("correspondent_id") correspondentId: String?="create", @Body body: JsonElement): Call<Void>

give default value to correspondentId as "create"
Now you can call this method without correspondentId ,and when you need to pass diffrent id then pass new correspondentId

Comment: @KishanMaurya I try this: myRestClient.updateCorrespondent(correspondent.toUpdateJson()), but I get compile error: Required String?, Found JsonElement

Comment: mtRestClient.updateCorrespondent(body = correspondent.toUpdateJson())

Comment: this issue still persists or resolve?

Comment: @KishanMaurya it's resolve. Thanks

Comment: I am posting this answer. If resolved then please upvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@POST("/correspondents/{correspondent_id}") fun updateCorrespondent(@Path("correspondent_id") correspondentId: String?="create", @Body body: JsonElement): Call<Void>
```

when you dont need correspondentId then call like

```
mtRestClient.updateCorrespondent(body = correspondent.toUpdateJson())
```